# How do I enable a template base upon comparison of values?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out how to "enable" a templated method based upon the comparison between two template arguments.

For example:

```
enum class LoggerLevel {
    FATAL = 0,
    ERROR = 1,
    WARNING = 2
};

template <LoggerLevel LOGGER_LEVEL>
class Logger {
public:
    template <LoggerLevel LEVEL>
    void log(const char* str);
};
```

I want a call to `log<WARNING>()` to compile to nothing (an empty function) if LOGGER_LEVEL < WARNING

I know this can be achieved through some form of template specialization. I have also been looking at std::greater_equal which looks promising but I can't figure out how to implement this behavior.

Comment: The shown code doesn't compile. Is the `Level` enum supposed to be defined inside `Logger`?

Comment: @cigien Yes, I had intended to declare the enum within the class. I didn't check to see if the code compiled, I just wrote it as an example.

Comment: Well, if the enum is declared inside the class, how is it going to be instantiated with a value of that enum as a template parameter? How would the code at the point of instantiating a `Logger` look like?

Comment: @cigien That makes sense. I moved the enum to an external enum class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. Desired behavior could be achieved by using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) when overloads are enabled or disabled based on log level.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum LogLevel {
    FATAL = 0,
    ERROR = 1,
    WARNING = 2
};

template <LogLevel LOGGER_LEVEL>
class Logger {
public:
    template <LogLevel MESSAGE_LEVEL>
    typename std::enable_if<LOGGER_LEVEL < MESSAGE_LEVEL>::type
    log(const char* /*str*/) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    template <LogLevel MESSAGE_LEVEL>
    typename std::enable_if<LOGGER_LEVEL >= MESSAGE_LEVEL>::type
    log(const char* str) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        Logger<WARNING> logger;
        logger.log<WARNING>("Warning 1!");
        logger.log<ERROR>("Error 1!");
        logger.log<FATAL>("Fatal 1!");
    }
    
    {
        Logger<FATAL> logger;
        logger.log<WARNING>("Warning 2!");
        logger.log<ERROR>("Error 2!");
        logger.log<FATAL>("Fatal 2!");
    }
}
```

Output would be:

```
Warning 1!
Error 1!
Fatal 1!
Fatal 2!
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I am curious though, when the log level is such that the empty function is used, if a string literal is passed to the function (e.g. logger.log<WARNING>("Warning 2!")), is the compiler smart enough to not even place that literal in data memory?

Comment: Yes. It is smart enough. You can look into assembly code here:
https://godbolt.org/z/KdMMxaM9q

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use constexpr-if to only compile the code you want

```
template <LoggerLevel LOGGER_LEVEL>
class Logger {
public:
  template <LoggerLevel LEVEL>
  void log(const char* str)
  {
    if constexpr (LEVEL >= LOGGER_LEVEL)
      // ... code
  }
};
```

Comment: I like this option as well. I believe my compiler supports C++17.